# Cross Correlation (xcorr in MATLAB) vs Pearson Correlation (corr in MATLAB)

Tags: correlation, matlab, cross-correlation

Are the values of `xcorr(x,y)` in MATLAB correlation values or not? I'm asking this because in MATLAB `xcorr(x,y,'coeff')` normalizes values. Is it normalizing covariance values to get correlations?

I'm confused if cross correlation values are necessarily between -1 and 1 like Pearson correlation values.

Also, I see from running an example that `xcorr(x,y,0,'coeff')` != `corr(x,y)`. Could someone explain this?

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your question here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/mGDawQlNIGU or here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832446/cross-correlation-coefficient

Comment: See Wikipedia on [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) and on [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient). Very different!

Answer (score 2):

The function `xcorr()` is used for calculating the time cross correlation of time series (Or any indexed signal).
The `corr()` function is all about calculating the correlation of so supposedly 2 random variables.

While the 2 coincide if used correctly and wisely pay attention that they basically normalize differently the operation (Hence you don't get what you expect).

In code:

```
vA = randn([10, 1]);
vB = randn([10, 1]);
xcorr(vA, vB, 0. 'coeff')
ans =

    0.3070
A.' * vB / sqrt((vA.' * vA) * (vB.' * vB))

ans =

    0.3070
corr(vA, vB)

ans =

    0.3425
vAA = vA - mean(vA);
vBB = vB - mean(vB);
xcorr(vAA, vBB, 0, 'coeff')

ans =

    0.3425
corr(vA, vB)

ans =

    0.3425
```

As you can see from the code above what's you missing is that `corr()` removes the mean of the data while `xcorr()` doesn't.

So `corr(vA, vB)` is equivalent of `xcorr(vA - mean(vA), vB - mean(vB), 0, 'coeff')`.